# Angular routing module don't redirect or bring to the component

Tags: angular

I'm trying to start an angular project but for some reason the default application is not working.

The application start without any error but the browser display an empty page instead of "home works!".

When I go to the login page, nothing happen and other links (like /hello) don't redirect me to the home.
I think my routing module is not working at all.
I can write anything in the url nothing happen.
Here the code :

**app-routing.module.ts :**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import {EdoxiaGuard} from './services/guard/edoxia-guard.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '/', component: HomeComponent, canActivate:[EdoxiaGuard] },
  { path: '/login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate:[EdoxiaGuard] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,
    { enableTracing: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const routingComponents = [LoginComponent, HomeComponent]
```

**app.component.ts :**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'edoxia',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'edoxia-front';
}
```

**app.module.ts :**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule, routingComponents } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ToolbarComponent } from './shared/toolbar/toolbar.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    routingComponents,
    ToolbarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html :**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**index.html :**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>EdoxiaFront</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <edoxia></edoxia>
</body>
</html>
```

**home.component.html :**

```
<p>home works!</p>
```

**home.component.ts :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**login.component.html :**

```
<p>login works!</p>
```

**login.component.ts :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**edoxia-guard.guard.ts :**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EdoxiaGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate() {
    return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS
Gnome version : 3.36.8
NPM version : 6.14.12
@angular/router@11.2.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the console? I think you would have gotten an useful error saying:

```
Error: Invalid configuration of route '/': path cannot start with a slash
```

So you should remove the slashes from your routes, to:

```ts
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate:[EdoxiaGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate:[EdoxiaGuard] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

Also I noticed that you are not importing `RouterModule`, which is needed.

app.module.ts:

```ts
imports: [
  RouterModule, <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  BrowserModule,
  AppRoutingModule, 
  BrowserAnimationsModule
],
```

Then your app should work as should. Check this **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-clrzrh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)**.

EDIT: Getting to run your project, the dev console would have helped you here too. It said...

```ts
Error: No base href set
```

So what you need to add to your index.html inside `head` tag, is:

```ts
<base href="/">
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and your example on Stackblitz. I downloaded the app but it didn't work. The browser only shows the "loading" on the page and no route works. I also don't have an error in the console logs.

Comment: As the code is so simple thus far, maybe upload the project on github (for example) and I can try and run it locally.

Comment: I created a project on github. https://github.com/icehandler/edoxia-front

Comment: Updated my answer. Please use the dev tools console (F12) it will give you useful errors, it would have helped you here too ;) https://i.imgur.com/EHLf00f.png

Comment: ... also the tsconfig was badly named, how have you run the project at all, it wouldn't run until I correctly named it.

Comment: Home works! :D   Thanks a lot for your tips and your time.

Comment: OK, cool! Glad we got it sorted out! :) Have a nice weekend and happy coding!